# Getting Matched ID from MERGE

Tags: sql-server, merge

In our application that records ticket purchases, we decided that if a customer's info as filled out on the order form matches a record already present, then we won't add a new record to our Customer table.

I am using a MERGE (SQL Server 2008) to insert only if the records don't match.  I have the need to try to OUTPUT the CustomerID on if the record matches (and isn't inserted) or if the record is inserted and a new CustomerID is created.  Is there a proper way to go about this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspMergeCustomer]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @lastName varchar(40),
    @firstName varchar(30),
    @email varchar(50),
    @emailNote varchar(100) = null,
    @address1 nvarchar(200) = null,
    @address2 nvarchar(50),
    @city nvarchar(50),
    @state char(2),
    @zip char(10)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE Customer WITH (HOLDLOCK)
    USING (VALUES (@lastName, @firstName, @email, @emailNote, @address1, @address2, @city, @state, @zip)) 
    Source (LastName, FirstName, Email, EmailNote, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Zip)
ON (Customer.LastName = Source.LastName
    AND Customer.FirstName = Source.FirstName
    AND Customer.Email = Source.Email
    AND Customer.AddressLine1 = Source. AddressLine1
    AND Customer.City = Source.City
    AND Customer.State = Source.State
    AND Customer.Zip = Source.Zip)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (LastName, FirstName, Email, EmailNote, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, State, Zip) 
    VALUES (@lastName, @firstName, @email, @emailNote, @address1, @address2, @city, @state, @zip)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.CustomerID AS NEWID;
END
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UPDATE-no-op in SQL MERGE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316669/update-no-op-in-sql-merge-statement)

Comment: The linked solution works perfectly.  Thank you.